# Is SubSonic's CodingHorror the only way to do WHERE ISNULL?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

I'm trying to do a simple UPDATE ... WHERE ISNULL() using SubSonic ActiveRecord and the only way I can get it to work is by using CodingHorror. eg:

```
    public void MarkMessagesRead(long? from_person)
    {
        if (from_person.HasValue)
        {
            _db.Update<message>()
                .Set(x => x.is_read == true)
                .Where(x => x.from_id == from_person && x.to_id == people_id)
                .Execute();
        }
        else
        {
            new SubSonic.Query.CodingHorror(_db.DataProvider, "UPDATE messages SET is_read=1 WHERE ISNULL(from_id) AND to_id=@toid", people_id).Execute();
        }
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code supplied by cantabilesoftware should work - the two issues have been fixed in current source on github!

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to do an "And(x => x.from_id).IsEqualTo(null)?

Comment: So I just tried this:

_db.Update<message>()
.Set(x => x.is_read == true)
.Where(x=>x.to_id == people_id).And(x => x.from_id).IsEqualTo(null)
.Execute();

but I get this:

SubSonic.Query.Update<message>' does not contain a definition for 'And'

Comment: Duh - whoops I meant to stick the And in the Where: "Where(x => x.to_id && x.from_id == null)"

Comment: Thanks Rob.  Tried that and it compiles and runs but no records are updated. (running against mysql).  The generated SQL is UPDATE `messages` 
 SET `is_read`=@up_is_read
 WHERE `from_id` = @0.  Should be ISNULL() ?  Has this been fixed recently?  I'm running a slightly old version of subsonic and reluctant to update right now as we're about to release.

Answer (score 0):

There's two reasons why this wasn't working.

Firstly, it should be `Where<message>()` not `Where()` :

```
db.Update<message>()
            .Set(x => x.is_read == true)
            .Where<message>(x => x.from_id == from_person && x.to_id == people_id)
            .Execute();
```

The `Where()` method has bugs - it loses the comparison type so everything becomes a comparison for equality and operators like < <= etc.. all get lost.  Also, it only uses the first comparison.  In the example above, the `&& x.to_id == people_id` is silently discarded.

Secondly, sub-sonic's support for `==null` and `!=null` has been commented out.

I've logged both of these issues in the sub-sonic's github:

- http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/issue/210
- http://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0/issues/issue/211